# oracle SELECT ... FOR UPDATE com PHP

Tags: php, oracle

Possuo a segunte consulta:

> SELECT proxNum FROM orcamento FOR UPDATE;
>
> UPDATE orcamento SET proxnum = proxnum + 1;

Ela serve para que eu possa captar o proximo numero de orçamento disponível e já fazer um update adicionando 1 unidade a esse numero. Isso deve acontecer antes que a aplicação quando usada por outro usuário capte o mesmo numero.

A consulta funciona perfeitamente, o banco usado é oracle 11g.

Porém não consigo aplicar isso na linguagem php, pois a nao sao aceitas 2 consultas de uma só vez. Já tentei usar cursores utilizando de oci_new_cursor, porém sem exito. Alguns trechos de código tentei adaptar de exemplos desse site [PHP oci_new_cursor Examples](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/oci_new_cursor/php-oci_new_cursor-function-examples.html) Se alguém puder me ajudar por favor. Já nem sei mais o que tentar.

Caso eu tente executar o código, são exibidos os seguintes erros:

- Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character. Fatal error:
- Could not execute statement.

---

```
<?php
include "config.php"; //arquivo de configuração
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

$query2 = "
SELECT proxnum FROM orcamento FOR UPDATE of proxnum;
UPDATE orcamento SET proxnum = proxnum + 1; ";

$s2 = oci_parse($c, $query2);
if (!$s2) {
    $m2 = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: ' . $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
} //prepara para a execução


$r2 = oci_execute($s2);
if (!$r2){
    $m2 = oci_error($s2);
    trigger_error('Could not execute statement: ' . $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}// executa a consulta

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Já pensou em utilizar uma Sequence do Oracle?

Você pode criar uma sequence e depois chamar o nextval dela, ela se auto incrementa por si só:

Ex: Criar uma sequence no banco ([documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm))

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_orcamento
 START WITH     1000
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

Depois você chama o comando nextval dela no seu insert:

```
INSERT INTO orcamento (nr_orcamento, ...) values (seq_orcamento.nextval, ...)
```

Desta forma você não precisa se preocupar em fazer o incremento e tem a garantia de sempre ter uma sequence válida, pois ela se auto incrementa mesmo sem dar commit.

Comment: Oi cleyton! Já pesquisei sobre e cogitei o uso, porém, eu precisava de algo que eu pudesse fazer apenas na minha aplicação. Existem outros programas utilizando o mesmo banco de dados, e a sequence afetaria  os outros programas. Porém agradeço pela dica, pode ser que futuramente eu faça dessa maneira.